# How to send a Hangout message from Google Plus

Tags: google-plus, google-hangouts

Google Hangout used to be accessible from Google Plus, at least it's demonstrated on [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kb5q5_oLZFU).

Currently I only found ways to send an e-mail via Gmail.

Is it possible now (2017) to click on a person on Google Plus and start a Hangout chat or video call?